# Remover documentos embutidos no MOngoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tenho uma coleção 'acervo', com documentos do tipo:

```
{
   'autor':'Fulano',
   'livros':[
      {'Título':'Livro A','páginas':200},
      {'Título':'Livro B','páginas':150},
      {'Título':'Livro C','páginas':300},
   ]
}
```

Quero remover um desses documentos embutidos (por exemplo, o Livro C. Estou tentando fazer isso com o comando $pull, mas sempre dá alguma mensagem de erro.
Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Coloca junto da pergunta a maneira como você está tentando remover, pra que seja possível verificar se você está rodando o comando certo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Inicialmente, você pode tentar desta forma:

`db.acervo.remove({'livros.Título': 'Livro C'})`

Você também pode utilizar a função update junto com o $pull para remover todas as correspondências exatas de um valor especificado do array;
No caso, ele irá remover o documento cujo a chave Título tiver o valor "Livro C".

```
db.acervo.update({}, 
{$pull: {livros: {Título: 'Livro C'}}})
```